# Multi-Program Calls in Linux using Nohup like

Tags: linux, tcl, nohup

Now I encounter a problem in Linux Enviroment.

This is the situation:
Program A calls Program B, and Program B calls Program C.

The Program B calls Program C using nohup so the Program C can run in the background, no matter we close Program B or not.

But the problem now is the Program A would be busy waiting Program C if the latter doesn't stop.

I know I can use nohup when Program A calls Program B, but it would cause that the Program A will call Program B and go the next stage without waiting for Program B.

This is I want: Program A calls Program B => Program B calls Program C => close Program B by UI and Program C running in the background, finally the Program A  will go to the next stage.

What should I do ? The programs are written in TCL.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: That is definitely not what should be happening. You should not use nohup to spawn a new process from tcl. Just use `fork`. See the tcl documentation for `fork`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest things that could possibly work is to run program C from program B something like this:

```
exec nohup tclsh programC.tcl >/dev/null </dev/null &
```

You can't interact with the subprocess in any meaningful way anyway, but that's what you get with using `nohup` effectively in the first place.

### Variations

You might also test if you actually need the `nohup`; it's *possibly* enough to do this:

```
exec tclsh programC.tcl &
```

The `&` must be at the end; it tells Tcl to run the subprogram in the background, and that could be sufficient for what you're doing.

Another thing to experiment with is if you can use `>@stdout <@stdin` as the redirections. They won't let program B interact with program C, but they might let the user do so.

Comment: If `B` gets launched from `A` and `A` is still running, the terminal `C` is attached to is still alive when `B` terminates. `nohup` is not required at all (or I'm missing something)

Comment: Oh, overlooked `You might also test if you actually need the nohup` .. IMO you are right with that +1

Comment: Thanks to Donal, if I use "exec tclsh programC.tcl &", would Program C get destroyed when the terminal window is closed? I use nohup because I am afraid of the program in the background would be killed.

Comment: @Jarkid OK, if you need _total_ disconnect then use the backgrounded nohup version with a full set of redirects. (You may want to add `2>/dev/null` — or probably to a file for logging/debugging — in that case too.)